# Typescript definition for an add mixin function

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is there a way to write a Typescript definition for the following mix-in helper?

I've this pattern in library.js, and I'd like to create the library.d.ts

```
// declaration in `library.js`
var mixin = {
  example: function {}
}

function addMixin(instance) {
  instance.example = mixin.example;
  return example;
}

// usage in `client.js`
class MyClass {}
let myInstance = addMixin(new MyClass());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way is to declare addMixin with generic type parameter T, and declare addMixin return type as [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) of T with mixin type.

For this to work, addMixin parameter has to be declared somehow to allow an assignment to `example` property - again, intersection type, but this time with optional `example` property could do the trick.

Then, you have to use type cast for `addMixin` return value - it would be nice to have some kind of [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types) to be able to express that it always has an `example` property after assignment, but type cast will do it for now. (I assume you want to return `instance` from it, `return example` in your question gives an error about undefined `example`).

So, `addMixin` implementation in typescript could look like

```
var mixin = {
    example: function () { }
};

function addMixin<T>(instance: T & { example?() }): T & { example() } {
    instance.example = mixin.example;
    return instance as T & { example() };
}
```

If the actual implementation is in javascript and you just need declaration file for it, it can look like

```
// declaration in library.d.ts
declare function addMixin<T>(instance: T & { example?() }): T & { example() };

// implementation in library.js
var mixin = {
    example: function() {}
};

function addMixin(instance) {
  instance.example = mixin.example;
  return instance;
}


// can be used in client.ts with library.d.ts
// tsc client.ts library.d.ts

class MyClass {}
let myInstance = addMixin(new MyClass());

myInstance.example();
```

Comment: Oh intersection is exactly what I need. I can't change library.js - how would that look in a definition file?

Comment: in general, function declaration looks just the same, with `declare` in front and function body omitted - I updated example code